# Concatenate with IMPORTDATA from Yahoo Finance

Tags: google-sheets, yahoo-finance, google-sheets-api

In an effort to normalize company names across a number of databases, I discovered that I can cross-reference company names with the Yahoo finance API, and get consistent naming across the board.

I'm using

```
=Transpose(ImportData("http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s="&A2&"&f=n"))
```

But that separates each word into a different column, so I then have to Concatenate the output in another column using the following:

```
=TRIM(CONCATENATE(F2," ",G2," ",H2," ",I2," ",J2," ",V2))
```

Is there a way to do it all in one go? I've tried using "min", which just outputs "0". Thoughts? I appreciate your help.

Comment: I'm not seeing "separates each word into a different column" with a couple of stock symbols that I tried. Please give a self-contained example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I've created a dummy dataset [HERE](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gZnaWnNZvcAO7IvuWnx7x-HWHFbs9KltpTtFW3xPL54/edit?usp=sharing) and tried to explain the problems in each column with a note. I previously tried normalizing these companies with a Regex, but I just couldn't get anything accurate enough for my total list of >10,000 companies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `join` to concatenate the output of importdata. Transpose becomes unnecessary because join works with columns, too.

```
=join(" ", ImportData("http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s="&A2&"&f=s"))
```

Or, if you need to trim it at the end (didn't seem necessary in your examples),

```
=trim(join(" ", ImportData("http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s="&A2&"&f=s")))
```

Comment: By the way, if you have a better method of normalizing the names, I'd love to hear it. I'll add some more company names to the dummy data. As stated above, it got too complicated with Regex (which I'm reasonably good at), so I thought this would be a better option even if it is painfully slow.

Comment: I'd use their stock symbol as an identifier: MSFT, AAPL, etc

Comment: I should probably explain this in more detail. I am using the NASDAQ/NYSE FTP to get a list of every public company trading on those exchanges (which includes the tickers). I then have a number of datasets with separate information about those companies, but those datasets don't have the tickers. I want to integrate those datasets, but something like a QUERY or VLookup won't work well enough without me normalizing those party names and combine the datasets. In the future, I would like to do include subsidiaries, but I understand that this brings in a whole new level of complexity.

Comment: I see the issue, but to get an answer you should post a separate question with some examples of company names from the other database. It's hard to propose a normalisation for text unseen.